# How to read all elements of stack without popping them?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I want to read all the elements of stack without popping them. I have looked up online and found that there is a 'peek' operation but that just returns the first element of the stack. How do I read the other elements of the stack? Please suggest the code for it in Java.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Depends on the implementation. But you wouldn't do that. A `Stack` is a LIFO data structure, you are only meant to see the top.

Comment: Note that `Stack` is a subtype of `Vector`, so you can use all the `Vector` methods - which include random access - to read the elements of a `Stack`.

Comment: Althought it's possible, as @templatetypedef said, you probably aren't thinking correctly of your problem. You probably shouldn't be using a `Stack` if you need to check all the elements on it.

Comment: It's fairly common to need to examine the top several entries in a stack.  (Eg, compiler syntax analysis may require this.)  But the stack you use needs to support the function.  Some do, some don't.  Since a stack is not a complex data structure, it's reasonable to implement your own if you need the function and it's not readily available from one of the pre-defined classes.

Comment: On the flip side: there have been times (when writing an expression evaluator) where I've needed to look at one or two elements below the top of the stack without popping them.  But not "all the elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to reiterate on the original answer, it seems like you need a different data structure... if you elaborate on why exactly you need to see all elements of the stack without the standard operations, then perhaps a suggestion can be made.  You've probably already thought of it, but if you pop off all of the elements and push them onto a different stack, then do the same back to the original stack, you can see the elements, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do this.

Comment: I am sorry but I just realized it's a silly question as I have figured out how to do that. I was implementing my own data structure for Stack using LinkedList. I just iterated through the whole stack using a temporary object and I was able to print the stack. Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about [the abstract data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), it depends on the implementation. A stack is usually implemented as either an array or a linked-list - either of these are easy to traverse. With **only** a stack interface (only init, push, top, pop and isempty methods, as per Wikipedia), it's simply not possible.

If you're talking about [the `Stack` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), that, as templatetypedef pointed out, implements [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), which has [a `get` by index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29) (along with a `size` method), and [an iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#iterator%28%29), either allowing you to iterate through it.

Comment: Of course, a problem is that Stack (or Deque) does not document how it uses the underlying Vector, and even if we assume it's the most obvious implementation, you need to do some arithmetic to calculate the Nth element from the top.

Comment: I was implementing using a linked list and I have realized it's just an iterating operation that will help me read all the elements of the stack. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @HotLicks 100% correct, although the question didn't state that some particular order is required (useful note nonetheless).